# Old window installed inset from exterior

Tags: windows, framing, exterior

This is my old window (single pane glass) and it is inset / indented from exterior wall about 2-3 in

[image]

If I replace with modern double pane vinyl, it will sit flushed against exterior wall.

So what is the reason for such 2-3" indented like that? I noted that it is sloping down for water run off.

Is it just an old way of doing thing? Or is there specific reason?

Comment: AFIK the replacement windows are to be installed in approximately the same position as the original windows. Replacement windows are secured by nails or screws directed radially outward into the rough 2x4 or 2x6 framing. In contrast original, new construction windows have a flange or rim that fits over the rough opening. They are nailed through the rim from outside the wall towards the interior living space.

Comment: Can the original sash be removed by taking off the stops on the inside?

Comment: Why do you state that the new window will be installed in the plane of the exterior siding? I think it will have a better appearance if it is installed where the original window is. Did you make your measurements at the location of the plane of the siding? Have you already ordered the replacement window?

Comment: The pane is parallel to the "meat" of the opening like that, making it easier to securely install simple and thin windows that don't have pre-attached frames. It's not an "old way" per se, they still build houses with sills for style, but it is more noticeable on single-pane glass, especially non-hung.